# Trying to only display 1 category using get_posts

Tags: categories, get-posts

I'm trying to only display posts from a certain category in a widget. I've tried it in a few different ways but it is still showing posts from all categories. Here's my code at the moment:

```
$posts = get_posts(array ('category'=>6, 'numberposts'=>$number, 'order'=>'DESC', 'orderby'=>'date'));
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            setup_postdata($post);....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the example given in the codex?

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $number, 'category' => 6, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'post_date'  );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This a modified version that should suit your needs. Are you also certain that this category exists?

**Edit**:

```
<?php $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null; $wp_query = new WP_Query('showposts=' . $numberposts . '&cat=6&orderby=date&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <!-- your content -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Comment: The category definitely exists. 
I did try this code before and I double checked then with the code you provided but it doesn't work. Interestingly, it also didn't change the order despite it being changed from DESC to ASC.

Comment: Try the code in my edit above, to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got 2 loops and maybe one before. Try to use [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) before or [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts).

Comment: No luck. Thanks though.

Comment: Try to use `'category__in'` as parameter. But dunno if all `query_posts()/WP_Query` arguments work there.